# Python check folder for changes in time period watchdog

Tags: python, performance, filesystems, python-watchdog

I have a large directory with around 450,000 files and new files are added every day. I have python code that scans the file name of each file to find the ones I need (ones with today's date in filename). This process is slow it can take one hour, and I am trying to speed it up. Is there a way I can get a list of files that were created today without scanning all the files? I have looked at watchdog which monitors filesystem changes but I dont see a way where I can run the program once and it finds all the files that were created in a certain time period (last 24 hours).

Comment: What operating system do you use? Windows and Linux supports different methods to list and sort files by cmd/terminal commands, and you can use them to fetch data quickly.

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: So you can run subprocess and use the output of the 'forfiles' command to iterate file names with given create date and other properties. Check out this link for details about this command and test it's runtime: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc753551(v=ws.11)

Comment: Forfiles can give me the list I am looking for but its slow, so it wouldnt be an improvement, and Id have to integrate this into my python program

Comment: what python code do you use at the moment? Are your files in your folder indexed?

Comment: pattern = "*20210929.hdf5"
files=[]

for dir,_,_ in os.walk(directory):
    files.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(dir,pattern))) 

This is the code I have but i think the bottleneck is windows accesing every file on the hard drive, I dont think its indexed, its not listed in Windows indexing options menu and I cant add it because its a work network drive  and i don't have permission. Do you think indexing will improve performance significantly? Would this take up a lot of space? There is 6TB of information in this folder